# Running a custom script using entrypoint in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-entrypoint

I modified the `docker-compose.yml` file as given on https://hub.docker.com/_/solr/ by adding a `volumes` configuration and a change in `entrypoint`. The modified file is as given:

```
version: '3'
services:
  solr:
    image: solr
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - ./solr/init.sh:/init.sh
      - ./solr/data:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores
    entrypoint:
      - init.sh
      - docker-entrypoint.sh
      - solr-precreate
      - mycore
```

I need to run this 'init.sh' before entrypoint starts, to prepare my files inside container.

But I get following errors:

> ERROR: for solr_solr_1  Cannot start service solr: oci runtime error:
>   container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"init.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Earlier I found about official image hooks in neo4j from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45169362/6207775). Is there a similar thing I can use here also?

**Update 1:** From comments below, I realized that dockerfile set `WORKDIR /opt/solr` due to which `executable file not found in $PATH`. So I tested by providing the absolute path to entrypoint by using `/init.sh`. But this also gives error, but a different one:

> standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format
>   error"

Comment: shouldn't it be ./init.sh ??

Comment: Thanks, that helped a bit. I tried `./init.sh` and it gave same error but then I tried `/init.sh` and that gives `permission denied`.

Comment: The dockerfile sets `WORKDIR /opt/solr`, so I guess it looks for `init.sh` in that path.

Comment: `permission denied`, so you might to make sure that `init.sh` has `+x` in the permissions (`chmod +x init.sh`)

Comment: I think thats right, WORKDIR may be the reason for `path not found`. So I tried giving absolute path

Update: My fault @philipp , the `/init.sh` gives permission denied when the file was not present. I mounted at wrong place. After mounting correctly, I got `exec format error`. Anyone knows how entrypoint works?

Comment: @Ayushya Permission denied usually means that you are missing the executable flag in the `init.sh` file. fix that with `chmod` locally and rebuild the image.

Comment: Thanks @Grimmy That was fixed! I rebuilt the image and I got `exec format error`

Comment: Just run `docker-compose exec solr bash` and try to run the scripts if you still have problems. It's normally a lot easier to troubleshoot inside the container.

Comment: That is an option, but I am preparing to ship this image and automate the build process and running `docker exec` will effect just my system. So I want it to be done by docker-compose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you need to map your volume to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

```
version: '3'
services:
  solr:
    image: solr
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - ./solr/init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh
      - ./solr/data:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores
    entrypoint:
      - docker-entrypoint.sh
      - init
```

From

https://hub.docker.com/_/solr/

> **Extending the image** The docker-solr image has an extension mechanism. At run time, before starting Solr, the container will
>   execute scripts in the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ directory. You can
>   add your own scripts there either by using mounted volumes or by using
>   a custom Dockerfile. These scripts can for example copy a core
>   directory with pre-loaded data for continuous integration testing, or
>   modify the Solr configuration.

The docker-entrypoint.sh seems to be responsible for running the sh scripts based on the arguments passed to it. So init is the first argument which in turn tries to run init.sh

```
docker-compose logs solr | head
```

**Update 1:**

I had struggled to get this to work and finally figured out why my docker-compose was not working while the `docker run -v` pointing to the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh was working.

It turns out that removing the entrypoint tree was the solution. Here's my final docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  solr:
    image: solr:6.6-alpine
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - ./solr/data/:/opt/solr/server/solr/
      - ./solr/config/init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh
```

my ./solr/config/init.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "running"
touch /opt/solr/server/solr/test.txt;
echo "test" > /opt/solr/server/solr/test.txt;
```

Comment: I was able find a workaround by including `init.sh` in a script which would run outside the container and then start the container. But this seems better!

Comment: sorry I have just tested this and it looks like its not working

Comment: I think it should be working after edits. Please check.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution that worked for me was modifying entrypoint by placing /bin/sh.It looked a bit like this afterwards

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
    - .:/code
    entrypoint :  
    - /bin/sh
    - ./test.sh
    ports:
    - "5000:5000
```

where test.sh is the required bash script to be run inside the container.