# Neo4J Docker container not starting after running EXTENSION_SCRIPT

Tags: docker, neo4j

I'm using docker-compose to create a neo4j service from the official image with the following Dockerfile :

```
FROM neo4j:3.3.4

ADD zz-docker/neo4j/neo4j-init.sh /scripts/

EXPOSE 7474
EXPOSE 7687
```

and docker-compose.yml

```
neo4j:
   environment:
     - EXTENSION_SCRIPT=/scripts/neo4j-init.sh
   build:
     context: ../
     dockerfile: zz-docker/neo4j/Dockerfile
   image: zz-neo4j
   container_name: zz-neo4j-01
   ports:
     - 7474:7474
     - 7687:7687
   networks:
     - zz-net
   volumes:
     - ../neo4j-data:/data
     - ../neo4j-logs:/logs

networks:
  zz-net:
    driver: bridge
```

The extension script is being used to pre-load a database dump on container start up, based on the post [create-neo4j-database-from-backup-inside-neo4j-docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166636/create-neo4j-databse-from-backup-inside-neo4j-docker) as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

# do not run init script at each container start but only at the first start
if [ ! -f /var/lib/neo4j/data/neo4j-import-done.flag ]; then
    echo "Importing neo4j-init.dump ..."
    /var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j-admin load --from=/var/lib/neo4j/data/neo4j-init.dump --database=graph.db --force=true
    touch /var/lib/neo4j/data/neo4j-import-done.flag
    echo "Import complete"
else
    echo "There is no neo4j-init.dump file or the neo4j import has already run."
fi
```

However after the import is complete the container fails to start reporting an error:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 218: exec su-exec neo4j: command not found
```

Without the EXTENSION_SCRIPT defined, the container starts-up without a problem (though the script for import isn't run).

Any suggestions gratefully received!

Comment: Have you achieved any progress on this?

Comment: I've been having this problem as well. I'm pretty sure that my code worked fine until when I was using neo4j 3.2 or older but now on 3.4.10 this problem has started.