# Problems loading dump file into Neo4J Docker Compose

Tags: neo4j, docker-compose

I'm trying to make a docker-compose file that starts a Neo4J database and loads a dump file in for immediate use. I dislike installing database systems locally when they are usually just as easy to toss in a docker file, and then are easier to handle and wipe out when needed. However, I just can't seem to get this working. When running instructions I've found online, the docker container just fails to start, without any sort of error message.

Docker-Compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  neo4j:
    container_name: 'neo4j'
    image: neo4j:latest
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/password
      - EXTENSION_SCRIPT=/neo4j-data/neo4j-init.sh
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"
    volumes: 
      - ./neo4j-data:/data
```

neo4j-init.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

# do not run init script at each container strat but only at the first start
if [ ! -f /tmp/neo4j-import-done.flag ]; then
    /var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j-admin neo4j-admin load --from=/data/data.dump --database=graph.db --force
    touch /tmp/neo4j-import-done.flag
else
    echo "The import has already been made."
fi
```

This was built entirely from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166636/create-neo4j-databse-from-backup-inside-neo4j-docker), and I've followed those instructions exactly, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still searching, you need to restore ownership of the `/data` folder to neo4j

Add this line after database load in `neo4j-init.sh`

```
chown -R neo4j /data
```

Answer (score -1):

You may find the following [article](https://medium.com/neo4j/flights-search-application-with-neo4j-dockerizing-part-1-bcb861dc0c83) helpful - it describes how to do exactly what you're trying to do